# How can I change disk size for new machine instance for Azure?

Tags: azure

I want to create a new NC6 instance (for my GPU and ML works). Few days ago I created my first instance for the NC6 instance, it was 150 GB standard SSD one, it was too much for me, so I tried to change the disk to low price one, but I noticed you cannot shrink or swap/change the disk to reduced size one or HDD one. So, I ended up deleting the instance and now trying to create a new one, but here, seems there is no way to change disk size, it seems you can change "OS disk type" to SSD to HDD, but no disk size e.g. 150 GB to 32 GB. So, How do I specify disk size for new machine instance for Azure? Thanks.

[image: https://yuis.xsrv.jp/images/ss/ShareX_ScreenShot_f2220036-99c5-49c1-abad-ee0caf8c4bd3.png]

Comment: I don't understand why someone voted "close". you voted "close" because you have no idea the answer? Or because you do know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk size of the OS disk is determined by the image of the VM that you choose.

When you create a VM you get a copy of the bace image, and that bace image has a size.

You cannot reduce the size, but you can increase it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk

Comment: I understand that. but it is you cannot know how much of disk size the OS has? does Azure have a list of OS disk sizes for each OSes e.g. for Ubuntu, for CentOS? Thanks.

Comment: The default OS size was recently increased from 30GB to 128GB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/default-size-images-changed-30-gb

Comment: In 2017 the default for Linux OS was 30 GB in 2017, they may have be increased at the same time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/linuxonazure/how-to-resize-linux-osdisk-partition-on-azure

Comment: A SSD costs almost double that of a HDD disk. So you can reduce the cost by choosing HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Bouncing off of Shiraz's answer. I was banging my head on this problem. I have a free account with Azure and I'm trying to keep it free by not using stupid options that incur charges. But the default Server 2019 images comes with 128GB with no option to use a smaller size. The P6 that comes with the free account is 64GB.

I found that if you go into all images, you can search for a [smalldisk] image. It comes at 32GB. In my case, I created the VM, shut it down, then expanded it up to P6. (Why wouldn't I use the full size that comes for free?)
[Screenshots for Reference (Imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpVeE.jpg)